# How do I change an rst code snippet :ref:`foo` to display as Foo?

Tags: restructuredtext

An rst document has :ref:`function-calls` and displays it on readthedocs as function-calls, but it is the beginning of a sentence. How do I change it to display as "Function calls"?

Context: https://viper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure-of-a-contract.html#functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Sphinx documentation of the role [`:ref:`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#role-ref):

> Labels that aren’t placed before a section title can still be referenced to, but you must give the link an explicit title, using this syntax:
>
> ```
> :ref:`Link title <label-name>`
> ```

So try:

```
:ref:`Function calls <function-calls>`
```